# Not able to click on a Link in web page

Tags: java, javascript, webdriver, testng

In my application,there is a link.  When I click on this link, then a child popup will appear.

In web driver+java+testng application automation script, the above scenario works fine for few test cases, but--after that--script does not click on link.  Due to this validation on child popup start to fail.

Comment: What have you already tried? Could you please share your source code? Can you share a link to your application?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, which will help you ask good questions and let the community provided better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following to accept/cancel popup:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

If it doesn't work, please post your script and share application link.

Comment: This is not an answer as you don't know what the author has tried. Without some code, you are simply guessing what the problem is.